# programmatically create a custom variable

Tags: magento2, admin, magento-1, installation

I followed the trace of a custom variable and I notice that it create entry on `core_variable_value` and core `core_variable` as well as in the logging table, I need a custom variable in one of my CMS codes but this needs to be done on the installation so the end user doesn't have to create it, is it possible to do it programatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Magento 1 answer

Thought this would be useful to share, this is how yo do it on Magento without adding it on any system.xml.

```
$variable = Mage::getModel('core/variable')
                  ->setCode('variable-code')
                  ->setName('Variable Name')
                  ->setPlainValue(0)
                  ->save();
```

Comment: Hi :). Do you know how I would implement this in Magento 2? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Magento 2 answer

In a comment a user asks how to programmatically create a custom variable for Magento 2. Interestingly, a question [referencing this one](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122017/updating-custom-variable-value-programatically) has a solution that can be adapted for use here.

In Magento 2, instead of `Mage::getModel('core/variable')` we have a class instance injected into the constructor. Then we can use that class instance in our methods:

```
<?php
namespace Foo\Bar\Wherever;

use Magento\Variable\Model\VariableFactory;

class Whatever {

    protected $_variableFactory;

    public function __construct(VariableFactory $variableFactory)
    {
      $this->_variableFactory = $variableFactory;
    }

    public function yourMethod()
    {
        $var = $this->_variableFactory->create();
        $var->setCode('variable-code')
            ->setName('Variable Name')
            ->setPlainValue(0)
            ->save();
    }

}
```