# updating custom variable value programatically

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, variables

I want to update the value of a custom variable programmatically, I am using magento 1.9.2

I have tried the solution given at [programmatically create a custom variable](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13730/programmatically-create-a-custom-variable) but this is for creating custom variable but I want to update the value of an existing variable, and also this solution is not working in magento 1.9.2

Any help regarding this issue?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
$code = 'variable-code';
$variable = Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode($code);
$variable->setName('Variable Name')
        ->setHtmlValue('Html Value')
        ->setPlainValue('Plain Value')
        ->save();
```

Comment: How we can set the value, say my custom variable name is "customVar" I want to set value "<span>I am here</span>". How we can achieve this using code?

Comment: updated ans pls check

Comment: try this : $code = 'variable-code';
     $variable = Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode($code);
     $variable->setName("customVar")
      ->setHtmlValue("<span>I am here</span>")
      ->setPlainValue("I am here")
            ->save();

Comment: Okay let me give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

## Magento 2 answer

For Magento 2+ you can use this in UpgradeData or UpgradeSchema:

```
// include the model
use Magento\Variable\Model\VariableFactory;

public function __construct(
      VariableFactory $varFactory
) {
      $this->varFactory = $varFactory;
}

// in your function or version_compare
$variable = $this->varFactory->create(); 
$code = 'variable-code';
$variable->loadByCode($code);
$variable->setName('Name Value, old or new')
         ->setHtmlValue('HTML Value, old or new')
         ->setPlainValue('Plain Value, old or new')
         ->save();
```