# Custom Variable get dynamic value based on Realtime condition magento2

Tags: magento2, php, email-templates, custom-variable

I have Create the custom variable programmatically like below.

[updating custom variable value programatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122017/updating-custom-variable-value-programatically)

Ex. I have created the **current_time** variable now I insert the variable in the email template.

Now when the email sent then that variable value have current time on this like it was sent 8:00 pm. then I want to set the time in variable automatically.

So Is it possible